# Can't run the ActionBarCompat sample

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-actionbar-compat

I am having trouble compiling and running the ActionBarCompat sample of Android 16. I have API level 16 as the build target selected, which seems to build fine, but when I try to debug these errors pop up. Of course I could change the min API level in the manifest, but what would be the point of that? I have made no changes to the sample, so how come it is not working properly?

```
Class requires API level 14 (current min is 3): android.view.ActionProvider SimpleMenuItem.java /ActionBarCompat/src/com/example/android/actionbarcompat    line 129    Android Lint Problem

Class requires API level 14 (current min is 3): android.view.ActionProvider SimpleMenuItem.java /ActionBarCompat/src/com/example/android/actionbarcompat    line 134    Android Lint Problem

Class requires API level 14 (current min is 3): android.view.MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener    SimpleMenuItem.java /ActionBarCompat/src/com/example/android/actionbarcompat    line 155    Android Lint Problem
```

I am thoroughly confused, any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I have added the @TargetApi(14) annotations, then added Lint suppres newApi to one of the methoeds and now it seems to be running fine. I am even more confused. Could anybody shed some light on what's going on?

Comment: Lint is not a compilation error.  You can clear these Lint errors in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, these samples are not kept up to date for each SDK iteration.
-First thing first, you have setted a min of `sdkversion = 3` ? That seems a little low to me. 7 (eclair) is I think the minimum version most projects should focus on. 
Lower level versions have a ridiculous market share and it will keep decreasing.

-These are Lint warnings. Lint is kinda new to Android, this is why this sample does not take it into account. It tells you about potential problems in your code. This warning means you are calling a level 14 class in a code that can run on a level 3 terminal. You should try to remove them with an `@TargetApi(14)` annotation. This annotation tells to Lint that you know what you are doing and this code will only run for sdk version=14 at minimum.

-Also, if you want to use the actionbar with any version of Android, what you really want to use is the open source ActionBar Sherlock library. One step at a time though :-)

Comment: So, basically, the answer is, the sample is kinda borked and doesn't run without modifications in newer environment? Thanks for the sherlock hint, I'll surely take a look at it.

Comment: Yep. The SDK is evolving rapidly and the Android team is probably not big enough to maintain all the samples.
I think they should do a better job at this... total beginners can be a bit lost with that kind of problems.
In Eclipse, you can use the quick fix feature to see the potential fixes for a problem. Also, I think that all Lint problems have an extended explanation accessible with a couple of clicks.
It is in fact a great addition to the Android development.
Without it if you don't check the minimum version of the objects you are calling you could have bad surprises while testing the app.

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest, you define `android:minSdkVersion="3"`, yet you are making calls to API level 14 classes/methods.

Lint will check these types of API calls and give you a warning.

Obviously in the `ActionBarCompat` the current API level is checked to ensure it is safe to make the call.

To remove the warning simply add `@TargetApi(14)` before the method where you make the call.

Comment: The thing is, I haven't defined anything, this is the Google-made sample. Additionaly, it's not a warning, but an error, but maybe that's what you meant :)

Comment: Moreover, adding an annotation should not fix something that doesn't run, right? Annotations do not change the behaviour of the java code, they only put some restrictions on it (they can cause errors, but should not remove them afaik)

Comment: Error, yes. But the annotation DOES remove it. Try it.

Comment: The annotation simply tells Lint: *Trust me. I know what I'm doing here. I enforced the necessary conditions to make sure this wouldn't get called on lower api levels.*

Comment: I guess I got it. It's Lint, not the compiler itself that is throwing the errors and preventing me from running the thing. That kinda makes sense.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Project build target to API level 14..in (project->properties->Android)

These are their requirments:

Due to the use of the native action bar and its related classes on Ice Cream Sandwich, the library requires that ***both*** it and your project are compiled with Android 4.0 or newer. The project also requires that you are compiling with JDK 1.6 in both your editor and any build systems that you may be using.

Comment: When I got to the Project > Properites > Android  selection of bulid targets, I don't even have API 14 availabe. What the heck? Why is not API 16 good enough? There should be some sort of backwards compatibility, right?

Comment: Targeting the last version of Android is a very good practice and is strongly encouraged by Google. Ideally you should never target a lower version than the last